# How to take string value from the variable and send to a search box

Tags: java, selenium

The 'name_asset' is a string variable which contain string values .

I want to take those values and send it to a search box randomly as per the index . is there any way to do that ?

```
List<WebElement> Asset = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-card__details']//h3"));

        for (WebElement list_value : Asset) {
            name_asset = list_value.getText();

            if (name_asset != null) {

                System.out.println("the vales are *****" + name_asset);
            } else {

                System.out.println("Assets count is zero");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Name_assey has only one value not values

Comment: PDHide - Sorry that might be the typo error .  if you have any put please provide

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> Asset = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-card__details']//h3"));
List<String> assetList= new ArrayList<String>();

        for (WebElement list_value : Asset) {
            name_asset = list_value.getText();

            if (name_asset != null) {
                 
                assetList.add(name_asset)
                System.out.println("the vales are *****" + name_asset);
            } else {

                System.out.println("Assets count is zero");
            }

        }

    }


   //to access text randomly
  Random rand = new Random();
  int index= rand.nextInt(assetList.size());
   assetList.get(index)
```

Store text to a list and use random index

Comment: Thank you , I will implement  and check .